# MSBuild error when Specifying Configuration and Platform on WPF Project via batch file

Tags: wpf, visual-studio-2010, msbuild, batch-file

I must confess I'm a bit of a noob when it comes to MSBuild and batch files, so do bear with me ;)

I have a folder structure which looks like this

```
/src
  /SLProject
        SLExampleProject.csproj
  /WPFProject
        WPFExampleProject.csproj
  ExampleSolution.sln
  Deploy.bat
```

The solution contains multiple silverlight WPF projects separate by folder at the level of /SLProject and /WPFProject. I am trying to create a batch file `Deploy.bat` to execute MSBuild on a subset of the Silverlight and WPF Projects, obfuscate the output and xcopy DLLs over to another folder.

I have a problem in my batch file related to MSBuild. When I specify both the Platform and Configuration for the first WPF Project to be build, I get the error "The OutputPath property is not set for project" ...

[image: MSBuild Error]

Here is the line of the batch file that causes the failure

```
call %windir%\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\msbuild.exe 
  /t:rebuild /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform="Any CPU"    
  Abt.Controls.SciChart.Wpf/Abt.Controls.SciChart.Wpf.csproj
```

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong here? I can confirm there *is* an Output Path set for this project, and the combination of platform=release and configuration=AnyCPU exists for the project being built and its dependencies.

Curiously removing the Platform="Any CPU" and the build is successful ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When building project files directly you must specify a Configuration and Platform combination that is defined in the project file.  By default Visual Studio 2010 will only create Debug|x86 and Release|x86 for .NET projects.  This isn't a problem when building from a solution file because by default it will map Platforms such as "Any CPU" or "Mixed Platforms" to one of the valid Platforms specified in the project files.

So you have two options, either specify "x86" for the Platform when building from your batch file or create a new Platform configuration for "Any CPU" for each project using the [Configuration Manager](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/kwybya3w%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) in Visual Studio.  Also, when you create an "Any CPU" Platform for a project it's actually called AnyCPU in the project file, so you will need to specify AnyCPU instead of "Any CPU" in your batch file.  However, when building a solution from the command line you will still need to specify "Any CPU", just an annoying inconsistency.

Comment: Hello Scott, thanks for your answer. In the Solution Properties under Configuration there is a platform configuration for Any CPU and Release for all projects in the solution - hence the confusion :S Although I wouldn't put it past me to make a noob mistake. I've never really done batch MSBuilds before ...

Comment: @Dr.AndrewBurnett-Thompson I updated the answer to clarify an inconsistency with "Any CPU" vs AnyCPU.  Basically, just change you batch file to specify AnyCPU and it should work.  To double check the actual Configuration|Platforms specified in a project files do the following: from Solution Explorer right click and select Unload for a project, then right click again and select Edit.  See what configuration platforms are specified in the PropertyGroup tags in the beginning of the file.

Comment: it is confirmed, I am an MSBuild noob. This worked perfectly. Thanks for the help!